# Trimming special characters from a CSV file

Tags: php, csv, trim

I have a CSV file with the content below:

```
1,a,,
255,,b,
255,,,c
```

This is my code to parse the file:

```
$fp = @fopen('1.csv','rb');
while (!feof($fp)){
  $data = fgets($fp, 4096);
  $data = rtrim($data, ',');
  echo $data.'<br>';
}
```

The result is the same as the original file. I don't know why? The follow content is what I want:

```
1,a
255,,b
255,,,c
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot about line end chars

Try

```
rtrim($data, "\n\r,");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$fp = @fopen('1.csv','rb');
    while (!feof($fp)){
    $data = fgets($fp, 4096);
    $data   = preg_replace('/\,+$/', '', $data);
    echo $data.'<br>';
}
```